# How can I compile a program while :Error ld returned 1 exit status is appearing

Tags: c++, windows

While creating my C++ project I found out some errors concerning my syntax but some other files and here is the errors I found:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\SUJET 1\EMPLOYE.o   EMPLOYE.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN7EMPLOYE6valeurE[.refptr._ZN7EMPLOYE6valeurE]+0x0): undefined reference to `EMPLOYE::valeur'.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o)   In function `main':
>
> C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c   undefined reference to `WinMain'
>
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\SUJET 1\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
>
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\SUJET 1\Makefile.win    recipe for target '"SUJET' failed

files:

**EMPLOYE.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include"EMPLOYE.h"

using namespace std;

EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(){};
EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(string n ,int m ,int i){
    nom=n;
    matricule=m;
    indice=i;
    int valeur = 10;
};

void EMPLOYE :: afficherEmploye(){
    cout << "votre nom est"<<nom<<"votre matricule est" << matricule << "votre indice est" << indice << endl;   
};

int EMPLOYE :: salaire(){
    return indice*valeur; //salaire
};
```

**EMPLOYE.h:**

```
#ifndef EMPLOYE_h
#define EMPLOYE_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class EMPLOYE{
protected:
    int indice;
    string nom;
    static int valeur ;

public:
    int matricule;
    EMPLOYE();
    EMPLOYE(string , int, int);
    void afficherEmploye();
    virtual int salaire();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please copy-paste error messages into the question, makes it easier to read. The third error is undefined reference to WinMain. Does your program contain a `main` function?

Comment: Also you should read about [Why using namespace std is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). This can become a real problem when used in a header.

Comment: i edited the errors part @churill 

then should i try to use std:: instead ?

Comment: Thanks :) Using `std::` is safer. In case the names get too long you can also use [namespace aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) or [type aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to shorten them.

Comment: The errors point to the fact that you're missing the function called `main`. This function needs to be a part of all c++ programs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the static variable explicitly.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include"doc.h"

using namespace std;

int EMPLOYE::valeur = 0;

EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(){};
EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(string n ,int m ,int i){
nom=n;
matricule=m;
indice=i;
valeur = 10;
};
void EMPLOYE :: afficherEmploye(){
cout<<"votre nom est"<<nom<<"votre matricule est"<<matricule<<"votre indice 
est"<<indice<<endl;
};

int EMPLOYE :: salaire(){
return indice*(EMPLOYE::valeur); //salaire
};

int main()
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Please also state it in words, not just code. Your example implies adding the main function to the `employe.cpp` file which defeats the purpose of splitting a class into a `.h` and `.cpp`.

Comment: Are you referring to your own link? If so, it says nothing about the fact that you must have a `main` function. And the purpose of a stack overflow answer is to ANSWER the question completely, without leaving uncertainties out. In no way am I telling you to code it for them. But that's actually what you've done. I'm asking you to explain, not just show the finished product.

Answer (score -1):

You're compiling a program without an entry point aka a main function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ return 0; }
```

It is required as it will be the entry point of your program, if you're building a library you might want to change your compiler settings. And of course, if you want things to happen, put something else inside the main, you can discard the parameters is you don't use them